# Why enabling Voice Processing on AVAudioInputNode changes channels count on its format?

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

I've noticed that enabling voice processing on `AVAudioInputNode` change the node's format - most noticeably channel count.

```swift
let inputNode = avEngine.inputNode
print("Format #1: \(inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))")
// Format #1: <AVAudioFormat 0x600002bb4be0:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
try! inputNode.setVoiceProcessingEnabled(true)
print("Format #2: \(inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))")
// Format #2: <AVAudioFormat 0x600002b18f50:  3 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved>
```

Is this expected? How can I interpret these channels?

My input device is an **aggregate device where each channel comes from a different microphone.** I then record each channels to separate files.
But when voice processing messes up with the channels layout, I cannot rely on this anymore.